# Парсер всех адресов сайта на PHP

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, парсер, динамические-массивы

Хочу написать парсер, который парсит все страницы указанного сайта.
Написал функцию, которая получает со страницы все ссылки, проверяет, чтобы они принадлежали тому сайту с которого скачиваю, добавляю в массив и удаляю дубликаты ссылок на эти страницы.

НО дальше не могу придумать, что делать. Вот набросал код, но он считывает с масива проходит по ссылкам которые были получены с первой странице.

```
$arr2 = array();
$arr = parseLink($url);
foreach ($arr as $value2) {
    array_push($arr2, $value2);
}
$arr2 = array_unique($arr2);

foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
    $arr = parseLink($value);
    foreach ($arr as $value2) {
        array_push($arr2, $value2);
    }
    $arr2 = array_unique($arr2);
}
print_r ($arr2);
```

Подскажите, как решить мне такую задачу? Возможно есть готовое решение?

Comment: Можете пояснить в чем, собственно, вопрос? А то `подскажите как решить`, а что решить непонятно.

Comment: Да вот думал как добавлять в массив новые адреса и проходить по ним. Я так понимаю, что теоретически надо выкачать весь сайт, чтобы собрать все адреса.

Answer (score 1):

Придумал такое решение, хотя мне кажется что это криво (( но все же

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
$arr3 = array($url);
$count=1;
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$url=$arr3[$i];
$arr1 = parseLink($url);

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    array_push($arr2, $value);
}
$arr2 = array_unique($arr2);

$arr3 = array();
foreach ($arr2 as $value2) {
    array_push($arr3, $value2);
}   
$count = count($arr3);
}
print_r ($arr3);
```

Comment: Усложняете. У вас в результате – массив уникальных ссылок. Перед тем, как вставлять туда очередную ссылку, проверяйте два условия: с этого ли она сайта и нет ли её уже там (ф-я [`in_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php))

Comment: Я в програмировании не очень, учу по мере потребности, посмотрю что за функция, спасибо за помощь))

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивный вариант

```
<?
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__DIR__) . '/errors.log');
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', true);
ini_set('display_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$urls = getLinks(array('url1'));
var_dump($urls);
exit;

/**
 * Получение всех ссылок сайта
 * @param array $urls_test
 * @param array $urls_result [optional]
 * @return array
 */
function getLinks($urls_test, $urls_result = array())
{
    if (!is_array($urls_test) || !$urls_test) return array();
    if (!is_array($urls_result)) $urls_result = array();

    foreach ($urls_test as $url_test) {
        if (in_array($url_test, $urls_result)) continue;//если ссылка уже была обработана
        $urls_result[] = $url_test;
        $urls_new      = parseLink($url_test);//запрос новых ссылок
        $urls_result   = getLinks($urls_new, $urls_result);//получение всех ссылок с новых ссылок
    }

    return $urls_result;
}


/**
 * Парсинг страницы для получения URL-адресов
 * Для теста
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function parseLink($url)
{
    switch ($url) {
        case 'url1':
            return array('url2', 'url3', 'url4');
            break;

        case 'url2':
            return array('url2', 'url5', 'url6');
            break;

        case 'url3':
            return array('url2', 'url4');
            break;

        case 'url4':
            return array('url6', 'url7');
            break;

        case 'url5':
            return array('url3');
            break;

        case 'url6':
            return array('url5', 'url2');
            break;

        case 'url7':
            return array('url1');
            break;
    }

    return array();
}
```

Comment: Думал по поводу рекурсии, но меня отговорили и сказали что можно другим путем решить))

Comment: Если вариант без рекурсии реализовать быстрее, то да. Если нет, то, по моему мнению, рекурсия подойдет на все сто. Рекурсию опасаются из-за того, что ее логику тяжело отлаживать. Но в этом примере все очень минимально, просто и наглядно.

Comment: Я вот не понял как задать предел или границу или условия выхода из рекурсии (( и пробовал цикл foreach для обхода ссылок из массива как вы, но почему-то программа обходила только ссылки полученные на первой странице, хотя здесь рекурсия и все может работать по другому. В любом случае спасибо )))

Comment: И еще я не понял зачем на вхрде передавать два массива , что это? Я хочу на входе передавать одну страничку, без разницы какую, и чтобы из нее начинался парсинг

Comment: Первый массив в аргументах функции - это список ссылок, с которых начинается обработка. В этом массиве должна быть хотя бы одна ссылка. Можно изменить и передавать только ссылку, а уж в функции проверять, что если ссылка, то создать массив, вставить в него эту ссылку и продолжить работу функции.

Comment: Для первоначального вызова второй массив можно убрать, внес обновление.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал такой алгоритм:

1. Есть массив ссылок на внутренние страницы `$internalLinks`
   (изначально - только одна ссылка на главную).
2. Есть массив ссылок `$checkedLinks`, которые мы уже запрашивали. Изначально пустой массив.
3. Идём по массиву `$internalLinks` в цикле do while пока есть `$internalLinks`, делая http-запрос и добавляя ссылки на внутрение страницы в `$internalLinks` (которых еще нет в `$checkedLinks` и `$internalLinks`). При извлечении очередной $internalLinks добавляем её в $checkedLinks и естественно удаляем из $internalLinks.

Т.о. мы пройдём все страницы сайта не более одного раза.

```
<?php

class Spider extends Parser_AbstractHttp
{
    const DOMAIN = 'example.com';
    const ITERATIONS_LIMIT = 5000;

    private $internalLinks = array();
    private $checkedLinks = array();
    private $iterations;

    public function runSpider($sleep)
    {
        $this->internalLinks[] = 'http://' . self::DOMAIN . '/';
        $this->iterations = self::ITERATIONS_LIMIT;

        $startTime = microtime(true);
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $i++;
            $url = $this->getNextUrl();

            $request = $this->getExpectedRequest($url);

            echo "#$i: try $url... ";

            try {
                $response = $this->getClient()
                    ->setMaxRedirects(2)
                    ->send($request);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $sleepTime = 7;
                echo $e->getMessage() . ". Sleeping $sleepTime... ";
                sleep($sleepTime);

                $response = $this->getClient()
                    ->setMaxRedirects(2)
                    ->send($request);
            }

            echo $response->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

            $body = trim($response->getBody());
            $body = $this->removeHTMLComments($body);
            $body = $this->_convertToUtf8($body);

            $page = new Html_Page($body);

            $this->saveAllInternalLinks($response, $page);

            sleep($sleep);
        }
        while (
            $this->internalLinks
            && $this->hasIterations()
        );

        $finishTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;

        echo 'Finally, finished within ' . round($finishTime, 2) . 's and '. (self::ITERATIONS_LIMIT - $this->iterations) . " iterations (sleep between http-queries {$sleep}s)." . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function getExpectedRequest($url)
    {
        $request = new Http_ClientRequest();

        $request->setHeaders(array_merge(Http_Browser::getNextRequestHeaders(), array(
            'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0',
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
            'Keep-Alive' => '3',
        )))
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->setUrl(new Http_Url($url));

        return $request;
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of links to internal pages of the site.
     *
     * @param Http_BaseResponse $response
     * @param Html_Page $page
     * @return array
     *   Http_Url links.
     */
    private function saveAllInternalLinks(Http_BaseResponse $response, Html_Page $page)
    {
        $tags = $page->getTags('a');

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $url = trim(mb_strtolower($tag->getAttribute('href')));
            $url = preg_replace('/#.*/iu', '', $url);
            $url = preg_replace('/&amp;/iu', '&', $url);
            if (preg_match('/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)(\?\d+?)?$/i', $url)) { // ссылки на картинки пропускаем
                continue;
            }

            try {
                $httpUrl = new Http_Url($url);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!in_array($httpUrl->getScheme(), array('', 'http', 'https'))) {
                continue;
            }

            $httpUrl = $response->absolutize($url);

            if (Net::detectDomain($httpUrl->getHost()) == self::DOMAIN) {
                if (
                    !in_array($httpUrl->toString(), $this->internalLinks)
                    && !in_array($httpUrl->toString(), $this->checkedLinks)
                ) {
                    $this->internalLinks[] = $httpUrl->toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function hasIterations()
    {
        if (!--$this->iterations) {
            echo 'Spider has exceeded iterations limit.' . PHP_EOL;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function getNextUrl()
    {
        $url = array_shift($this->internalLinks);
        if ($url) {
            $this->checkedLinks[] = $url;
        }

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что за класс такой `Parser_AbstractHttp`?

Comment: самописный класс, у меня парсеры наследуют его, абстрактный парсер. Имеет метод getClient() - возвращает curl-клиент - объект для лаконичной работы с curl. Я бы привёл код класса, но он громоздкий и не относится к сути вопроса.. к тому же еще содержит "левые" методы и зависит от других классов..

Comment: ну, значит, ваш ответ не имеет смысла, потому, что его нельзя использовать без `Parser_AbstractHttp`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я хотел идею подать (алгоритм). Ок, чуть попозже исправлю, чтобы использовался только чистый curl без лишних классов..

Comment: интересно было бы посмотреть как оно полностью все работает ))